# I would like to be able to use this piece of jQuery code multiple times per page

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have the following piece of code wrapped within an anonymous function which handles "tabs" for me:

```js
$(function () {

  var tabs       = $('.js-tabs-container > div');
  var tabNavLink = $('.js-tabs-nav a');

  tabs.hide().filter(':first').show();

  tabNavLink.click(function () {
    tabs.hide();
    tabs.filter(this.hash).show();
    tabNavLink.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    return false;
  }).filter(':first').click();

});
```

However I can only use it for a single instance of tabs per page. I'm fairly new to programming and JS so I would like some pointers in terms of how I would go about this.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here's a JSFiddle of the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Zm6dd/

Comment: would you please share your html code as well?

Comment: Sure, here's a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zm6dd/

Comment: okay what's wrong with the fiddle? works fine I suppose!

Comment: Take a look at it now.http://jsfiddle.net/Zm6dd/2/ Check out how the tabs from the first set are disappearing as well.

Answer (score 0):

here you go, you just needed to find the right selection: http://jsfiddle.net/Zm6dd/3/

```
$(function () {

  var tabs       = $('.js-tabs-container > div');
  var tabNavLink = $('.js-tabs-nav a');

  tabs.hide().filter(':first').show();

  tabNavLink.click(function () {
    $(this).parent().next('.js-tabs-container').children('div').hide();
    tabs.filter(this.hash).show();
    tabNavLink.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    return false;
  }).filter(':first').click();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with in the end.

https://github.com/sprawsm/sprawsm-tabs/